# Flask video streaming with rendered template

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I've implemented DWA path planning algorithm in C with Python bindings and I want to create a web application as a demo. The "robot" will follow the mouse using the DWA and the user can draw walls to create objects. I have implemented this in Python using OpenCV mouse events. To port this to a web application, I started by getting the mouse positions from the page.

```html
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(function() {
        $(document).bind('mousemove', function(event) {
            $.post( "/mouse_events", {
                x: event.clientX,
                y: event.clientY,
            });
            return false;
        });
        $(document).bind('mousedown', function() {
            $.post( "/mouse_events", {
                click: 'true'
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

```python
@app.route('/')
def index():
    print(type(render_template('mouse.html')))
    return render_template('mouse.html')

@app.route('/mouse_events', methods=['POST'])
def background_process_test():
    data = request.form
    print(data)
    return ""
```

This part of the code works perfectly. I can retrieve the x, y positions of the mouse from the page. Next, I need to stream the rendered simulation data to the page. The below code streams from the webcam for testing.

```python
@app.route('/stream')
def streamed_response():
    global cap
    @stream_with_context
    def generate():
        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            test = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                    b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + test + b'\r\n')
    return Response(generate(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Finally, I need to combine them together. I have tried to concat the rendered template with the frame. Although the streaming works, I can no longer retrieve the mouse data. Is there a way to combine these two ? I will probably have a problem with the frame position because the mouse position data is relative to the top left corner. It will be awesome if I can stream frames
at the top left corner.

```
yield (str.encode(render_template('mouse.html')) + b'\r\n' + b'--frame\r\n'
         b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + test + b'\r\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple.
The video is streamed in another /page and referenced from the index page.
I have added the below code to my template HTML. I have used CSS to make the video
appear at the top left corner without gaps. `<img src="{{ url_for('frame') }}">`
the frame is the name of the function.

```html
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>

<html>
  <body>
    <img src="{{ url_for('frame') }}">
  </body>
</html>
```